# Header and Code in C++ classes

Tags: c++, header

I just started on a few C++ tutorials, and I have run into something that I just can't seem to make much sense of.

In C++ it seems people are using a code file and a header file, for me this just seem inconvinient. Why would I want to swap around between two files just to write a simple getter method.

Is it considered the "correct" way to use headers in C++? Or is it just the tutorial I have picked up that uses this?

I get the idea of splitting code to make it look more clean, but is it good for anything else other than that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you know what function prototypes, class declarations, and template classes are, then it will all make sense.

Comment: No offence, but what this question has to do with java?

Comment: I have java experience, which I wanted to write but ended up removing it. Forgot to remove the java tag, my mistake :( I am aware of function prototypes and such, by why not just put it in the top of the file so you can scroll up and access it there, instead of swapping files?

Comment: @Aveneon At the top (or "head") of *which* file would you put it? It could be used in hundreds of places. (Swapping files is way faster than scrolling back and forth, too.)

Comment: Headers  include the interface of your implementations and sometimes it include whole inline implementations like in case of templates. and it's also a very important tool for code reuse (imprtant feature of c++), so you can hide your compiled code and show only your code interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about using the class you wrote in other files. If you had the class definition in a separate file, you could help the compiler to figure out how to use the class by including the header file in places where you are planning to use this code.

The compiler only needs to know whether you are using the classes right(it does not care about how to run it, until linking), therefore all you need to give the compiler is the declaration of the class(header file), to do the error checking. When you say `"include"`, the preprocessor just copies and pastes the header file contents into the new file, so that the new file now knows how to use the class you wrote.

Comment: Okay I think I understand it now, thanks for the explaination (to all of you!) :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some reasons for using hpp(header)- and cpp(code)-files. One of them is the following:  A library (dll- or so-file) cannot be "used" like a jar-file in java. If you write a library,  you have to provide declarations of the classes, methos,... in form of a hpp-file.

Answer (score 0):

A header file in c++ stores alot of information, if c++ have been made using every single "header" file in c++ in each program you make, when you then write a function from iostream for example, the program will go through every single header file just to find the right header file. so instead they made the #inlcude function in c++, so you could specify where your functions are from.

And when you create a program you could make own header files, so the code is more nicely set up. and then instead of having to make alot of lines of code in one main source file, you could import others. like if you are making a game, one header file for Animals and in that header file you have a Class for Cats, and one for dogs. having a more clean code.

Comment: Can't the .cpp file be included instead of the header, and then write the prototypes of the functions at the top of the .cpp file instead of in the header? 1 header is paired with 1 cpp file after all isn't it?

Comment: "1 header is paired with 1 cpp file after all isn't it?". No, not always. Think how the C++ standard library is used.

Comment: Yes they can, but people then mosly have a cpp file and a header for that particulary cpp file. so that you have a Dogs cpp and a dogs header file that connects with it. like main.cpp for using all of the headers. making a cpp file for + and - and then one for somthing else, and then calling one cpp file through main todo that.

Answer (score -1):

In C/C++, headers are used to share the class structure (among other things) between classes.

so one can use

## include "classFOO.h"

in classBAR.h (or classBAR.cpp) and use classFOO.